# Apache 2.4 SSL Config

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I've got a question regarding ssl config for apache 2.4. I got the following ssl settings for my vhost. There are more than 1 Directory but the config is mostly the same, only IPs are different. If I active the the three commented lines the apache should check the requests against the cert and not just pass the request through, correct? I assume the apache breakts the encryption for all requests from the internet and re-encrypts again to pass the request on. Am I right? Is there a way to not break the encryption and just delegate the cert checks to the next system?

```
RequestHeader set ClientProtocol HTTPS
SSLEngine On
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH

SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file.key

 <Directory /folder-name>
    #SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
    #SSLVerifyDepth 1
    #SSLOptions +OptRenegotiate +ExportCertData

    ProxyPass https://10.20.30.40:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse https://10.20.30.40:8443/
</Directory>
```

Thanks for your help guys and regards. Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this Apache acting as a proxy terminates SSL. It then makes or reuses a pooled SSL connection to the backend.

There's no way to truly let the backend think it's handshaking with the client unless it accessed apache as a forward proxy using the mod_proxy_connect module.

Some application servers accept the body of the client certificate in a proprietary header, making that identity available in the backend server. But they are not actually authenticating it in the handshake like the proxy/apache has done.